# VS2013 'Go To Definition' disabled every time I open it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

**EVERY TIME** I open Visual Studio 2013 my 'Go To Definition' is disabled.  I can close VS2013 and delete suo, re-open it and everything works fine. But if I open new instance of VS2013, 'Go To Definition' is disabled.

Is anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: This does happen sometimes, but the standard advice is to just delete the `suo` file, which you are already doing.  Out of interest, is this happening in an ASP.Net project?

Comment: yes, this is happening to ASP.net project.

Comment: I don't know if this will helper but here it goes: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5562f8f3-8fee-4080-83c1-7dbba8dadd4a/go-to-definition-is-disabled-in-visual-studio

Comment: Deleting the suo file worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin had updates available.  After updates were installed the problem went away.